# I can not use java.sql.date in java program correctly, it seems like there are some problems at the result set

Tags: java, sql

```
 String content = "SELECT * FROM " + "floor" + floor + " WHERE Roomnumber ='" + roomresult + "'";
                System.out.println("next query->" + content);
                statement.execute(content);
                ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();

Date u = rs.getDate("CheckIn");
```

> I want to transform the java.sql.date into java.util.date. I think the
>   final sentence is correct , but the java told me that there is a
>   NullPointerExceptio

Comment: ***PLEASE*** read this: [SQL Injection and How to Prevent It?](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection). What you're doing is **extremely** unsafe and is a security flaw in your application.

Comment: also you probably wanted to use `statement.executeQuery(content)`, else you won't have a result

Comment: You shouldn't be using `java.util.Date` anyway. Even if you had to load a `java.sql.Date` from the database, it's best to convert it to the appropriate class from `java.time`. It's also possible to get the value as the appropriate type using `getObject` in most modern JDBC drivers.

Comment: So what is the exactly data type i should use to represent the data from database

Comment: You can take the reference from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784523/how-to-get-date-datatype-from-sql-database-to-java

Comment: Most likely the type you need is `LocalDate`.

Answer (score -2):

if u want convert java.sql.date to java.util.date, use :

```
new java.util.Date(rs.getDate("CheckIn").getTime())
```

NullPointerException , may be CheckIn cloum not exist, or it be null;

pleas make sure CehckIn field exist and is not be null;